# Problem with nested if statements

Tags: conditionals, nesting, ifthenelse

I'm trying to use some nested `if` statements to decide if a file exists and what kind of loadings are possible:

```
\IfFileExists{./emoji.sty}{
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage[bw,font=seguiemj.ttf]{emoji}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{ifluatex}
    \ifluatex
      \usepackage[bw,font=Symbola_hint.ttf]{emoji}
      \usepackage{fontspec}
    \else
      \usepackage[bw]{emoji}
    \fi
  \fi
  \newcommand{\doxygenemoji}[3]{
    \IfFileExists{bw/#3.png}{
      \emoji{#3}
    }{
      #1
    }
  }
}{
  \renewcommand{\doxygenemoji}[3]{ #1 }
}
```

but unfortunately I get the error message:

```
! Extra \else.
\IfFileExists ...ileonpath {#1}{#2}{#3}}\fi \else
                                                  \closein \@inputcheck \ede...
l.60 }
```

where line 60 is the last closing bracket (`}`).

(Not yet a real MWE but hopefully I can get some hints already).

Comment: Load `ifluatex` before starting `\IfFileExists`; otherwise `\ifluatex` is not a conditional unless you are using `luatex` and therefore a missing conditional error ensues.

Comment: @egreg, but one still needs the double `##`, correct?

Comment: Yes, I was explaining the “apparently doesn't like the `\ifluatex` conditional“ in Phelype's answer. By the way, you have several spurious spaces in your code.

Comment: the ones with the renewcommand (should be newcommand) around the `#1` are known. Which others?

Comment: @egreg Ooh, that explains the problem with the conditional. Same problem as in my question about `docstrip` a few weeks ago. I'm a slow learner :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to double the parameter characters because `\IfFileExists` grabs the true and false branch as arguments. Also, it apparently doesn't like the `\ifluatex` conditional. You can use `iftex`'s conditionals:

```
\usepackage{iftex}
\IfFileExists{./emoji.sty}{
  \ifXeTeX
    \usepackage[bw,font=seguiemj.ttf]{emoji}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \else
    \ifLuaTeX
      \usepackage[bw,font=Symbola_hint.ttf]{emoji}
      \usepackage{fontspec}
    \else
      \usepackage[bw]{emoji}
    \fi
  \fi
  \newcommand{\doxygenemoji}[3]{
    \IfFileExists{bw/##3.png}{
      \emoji{##3}
    }{
      ##1
    }
  }
}{
  \newcommand{\doxygenemoji}[3]{ ##1 }
}
```

Or, to avoid doubling the parameter characters and for an extra degree of robustness you can use `expl3`'s conditionals:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\file_if_exist:nTF { ./emoji.sty }
  {
    \sys_if_engine_xetex:T
      {
        \usepackage[bw,font=seguiemj.ttf]{emoji}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
      }
    \sys_if_engine_luatex:T
      {
        \usepackage[bw,font=Symbola_hint.ttf]{emoji}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
      }
    \sys_if_engine_pdftex:T
      {
        \usepackage[bw]{emoji}
      }
    \cs_new:Npn \doxygenemoji #1 #2 #3
      {
        \file_if_exist:nTF { bw/#3.png }
          {
            \emoji { #3 }
          }{
            #1
          }
      }
  }
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \doxygenemoji #1 #2 #3
      { ##1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two errors in your code. The first is loading `ifluatex` inside a conditional; if the code is skipped (because the engine is XeLaTeX), `\ifluatex` will not yet be a conditional, but an undefined token, resulting in an unbalanced conditional.

The second error is not doubling `#` in the definition.

I'd reorganize the code in a different fashion, avoiding complicated code in the true and false branches of `\IfFileExists`.

```
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

\newif\ifemoji
\IfFileExists{./emoji.sty}{\emojitrue}{\emojifalse}

\ifemoji
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{font=seguiemj.ttf}{emoji}
  \fi
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{font=Symbola_hint.ttf}{emoji}
  \fi  
  \usepackage[bw]{emoji}
  \newcommand{\doxygenemoji}[3]{%
    \IfFileExists{bw/#3.png}{%
      \emoji{#3}%
    }{%
      #1%
    }%
  }
\else
  \newcommand{\doxygenemoji}[3]{#1}
\fi
```